# Fixing proof that if $\overline{A}\cap B=A\cap\overline{B}=\varnothing$, there exists $U,V$ such that $A\subset U$ and $B\subset V$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I tried to prove the following theorem:

> Let $X$ be a metric space and $A,B\subset X$. Suppose that $\overline{A}\cap B=A\cap\overline{B}=\varnothing$. Then there exists two disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $A\subset U$ and $B\subset V$.

My proof was the following:

> If $a\in A$, there exists $r_a>0$ such that $B(a,r_a)\cap B=\varnothing$. Otherwise, we would have $a\in\overline{B}$. (We could construct a sequence in $B$ that converges to $A$.) Similarly, if $b\in B$, there exists $r_b>0$ such that $B(b,r_b)\cap A=\varnothing$. Let
>       $$\;\;U=\bigcup_{a\in A}B(a,\epsilon r_a) \;\text{ et }\; V=\bigcup_{b\in B} B(b,\epsilon r_b),$$
>       where $\epsilon>0$ will be chosen later. Clearly, $A\subset U$ and $B\subset V$. If $U\cap V$ were not empty, there would exist $x\in B(a,\epsilon r_a)\cap B(b,\epsilon r_b)$, where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. So, by the triangular inequality:
>       $$d(a,b)\leq d(a,x)+d(b,x)<\epsilon(r_a+r_b).$$
>       Since $a\notin \overline{B}$, $d(a,B)>0$. However, if we take $\epsilon=d(a,B)/(r_a+r_b)$ we have 
>       $$f_B(a)\leq d(a,b)<\epsilon (r_a+r_b)=f_B(a),$$
>       which is absurd!

Now, I realised that I cannot take such $\epsilon$ since $a$ and $b$ depend on it. It seems intuitive to me that every $0<\epsilon<1$ would work but I can't figure out how to prove it.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292103/if-overline-a-cap-b-a-cap-overline-b-varnothing-a-cup-b-is-disconnec?rq=1) (with an answer that should work)

Comment: @MichaelBurr In fact, this answer works. However, I already know how to prove this (my teacher showed me the same proof that is in this post). But I would like to know how to fix my "proof".

Comment: Another [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2755700/in-principles-of-mathematical-analysis-why-does-rudin-define-connectedness-by-s?noredirect=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is almost fine, but however it does not work for any $\varepsilon \in ]0,1[$ : in $\mathbb{R}$, take $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\{1\}$. Then you can have $r_0=r_1=1$, but with $\varepsilon > \frac{1}{2}$, the open sets $B(0,\varepsilon\cdot r_0)$, $B(1,\varepsilon\cdot r_1)$ are not disjoint !

**To make your proof correct :** note that it works with $\varepsilon\in ]0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

Indeed, it would give you at the end of your proof $d(a,b)<\frac{1}{2}(r_a+r_b)$, but by definition, $A$ does not intersect $B(b,r_b)$, so you have $d(a,b) \ge r_b$ and similarly $d(b,a) \ge r_a$.

This gives you $d(a,b) < d(a,b)$ : absurd.

Comment: Just take $\varepsilon = \frac12$ and be done with it, I say.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma That's absolutely right

Answer (score 2):

As a remark into general topology: being able to separate such sets $A$ and $B$ by open sets, is called being "completely normal" and in all spaces this is equivalent to the fact that all subspaces of $X$ are normal (hereditarily normal). See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/431125/4280) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1724315/4280).

And as all metrisable spaces are normal, and all subspaces of metrisable spaces are metrisable, all metrisable spaces are hereditarily normal so completely normal: we can separate all $A$ and $B$ with $\overline{A} \cap B = \emptyset = A \cap \overline{B}$ by disjoint open sets.